# Wrong type in shared_from_this() in inherited class (is there a dyn.type-aware shared pointer?)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I have a base View Controller class that uses `enable_shared_from_this<>`

```
class ViewController :
public std::enable_shared_from_this<ViewController>
{ // ...
};
```

and a child:

```
class GalleryViewController : public ViewController {
     void updateGallery(float delta);
}
```

the problem arises, when I try to pass my current instance to 3rd party (say lambda function to be scheduled somewhere)

There is a (rare) condition that the instance (`GalleryViewController`) will deallocate, so I cannot capture 'this' directly, I need to capture the shared group with `shared_from_this()`:

```
void GalleryViewController::startUpdate()
{
    auto updateFunction = [self = shared_from_this()](float delta)
    {
        return self->updateGallery(delta); // ERROR: ViewController don't have updateGallery() method!
    };
    scheduler->schedule(updateFunction); // takes lambda by value
}
```

The problem is that `shared_from_this()` returns a `shared_ptr<ViewController>` that doesn't have the `updateGallery()` method.

I really hate to do `dynamic_cast` (or even static in this case) it's a maintenance nightmare. And the code is ugly!

```
updateFunction = [self = shared_from_this()](float delta)
    {
            auto self2 = self.get();
            auto self3 = (UIGalleryViewController*)self2;
            return self3->updateGallery(delta);
    };
```

Is there any default pattern to solve this problem? dynamic-type aware shared pointer? Should I double inherit the child class with `enable_shared_from_this<GalleryViewController>`?

Comment: Is `*this` already managed by a `shared_ptr`? If not, then there's no way to solve the deallocation issue.

Comment: You generally cannot get the best of both worlds w.r.t. polymorphism; both the ability to pass around a base class pointer, and the ability to easily call functions on the "actual" type. dynamic casting is necessary. Might be easier to make a virtual function in the base.

Comment: @AndyG sure, but the Derived classcould somehow "override" the parent-inherited enable_shared_from_this<Base> template class' methods, right? in other words, it would be great if shared_from_this() on derived class would return the shared_ptr<Derived> specialization (because I invoke this method in actual Derived instance and not through the Base pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void GalleryViewController::startUpdate(bool shouldStart)
> {
>     if (shouldStart == false) {
>     updateFunction = [self = shared_from_this()](float delta)
>     {
>         return self->updateGallery(delta); // ERROR: ViewController don't have updateGallery() method!
>     };
>     scheduler->schedule(updateFunction); // takes lambda by value
> }
> ```
>
> The problem is that `shared_from_this()` returns a
>   `shared_ptr<ViewController>` that doesn't have the `updateGallery()`
>   method.
>
> I really hate to do dynamic_cast (or even static in this case) its the
>   maintenance nightmare. And the code is ugly!

That is what [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) and [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) are for. You don't have to use `.get()` to obtain a raw pointer before casting.

```
void GalleryViewController::startUpdate(bool shouldStart)
{
    if (shouldStart == false) {
    updateFunction = [self = std::static_pointer_cast<GalleryViewController>(shared_from_this())](float delta)
    {
        return self->updateGallery(delta);
    };
    scheduler->schedule(updateFunction); // takes lambda by value
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend static_pointer_cast unless OP can guarantee that the cast is always correct. dynamic_pointer_cast is safer.

Comment: @AndyG, correct. However, I can infer that if No UB was invoked prior to calling `GalleryViewController::startUpdate(bool shouldStart)`, then `static_pointer_cast` will be just fine. Because, within the current member function,`this` is of type `GalleryViewController*`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @WhiZTiM thats right, the function `startUpdate` is very specific to child class so this is always `GalleryViewController*`. My only concern is why its not possible to `override` somehow the shared_from_this() method of inherited template `enable_shared_from_this` to match the actual derived class. I'm calling the shared_from_this() from this actual Child Class (not by Base pointer) so the type is known at compile time. Is there any way to re-inherit `enable_shared_from_this<Base>` to `enable_shared_from_this<Derived>` and override the method? Or I am saying silly thing?

Comment: @barney, unfortunately, `shared_from_this()` isn't a virtual function and cannot be overridden.

Comment: @WhiZTiM all functions can be overwritten except constructors and destructors. What you can't ensure is which version is going to be called if the function is not virtual (when virtual, the most derived class version is called; if you're not in the constructor or destructor). However, in this case it would not be required. So barney could have created his own `shared_from_this()` in his `GalleryViewController` class and `return std::static_pointer_cast<GalleryViewController>(shared_from_this());`. That way, if he is to need the smart pointer many times, he has a single _hidden_ cast.